# I want to refactor the code to have less functions

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about refactoring my code to be more concise:

```js
const an1 = document.getElementById("an1");
const bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1");

bt1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (an1.value.toLowerCase() === "test") {
    document.getElementById("bt1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("an1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("wo1").style.display = "initial";
  } else {
    bt1.innerText = "Wrong!";
    document.getElementById("bt1").style.background = "red";
  }
});

const an2 = document.getElementById("an2");
const bt2 = document.getElementById("bt2");

bt2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (an2.value.toLowerCase() === "test1") {
    document.getElementById("bt2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("an2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("wo2").style.display = "initial";
  } else {
    bt2.innerText = "Wrong!";
    document.getElementById("bt2").style.background = "red";
  }
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="c1"><input id="an1" placeholder="test" type="text" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" /><a id="wo1" style="display: none;">test</a><button id="bt1">Submit</button></td>
  <td class="c1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="c2"><input id="an2" placeholder="test1" type="text" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" /><a id="wo2" style="display: none;">test1</a><button id="bt2">Submit</button></td>
  <td class="c2">test1</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you must learn about event delegation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, update the arrays if this fucntionality requires for others field too.

```js
// change below arrays if you need this functionality for more fields

const expectedElementAnswer = [{ id: 'an1', expectAns: 'test' }, { id: 'an2', expectAns: 'test1' }];
const btnElementList = [
        [{ id: 'bt1', displayValue: 'none' },{ id: 'an1', displayValue: 'none' }, { id: 'wo1', displayValue: 'initial' }],
        [{ id: 'bt2', displayValue: 'none' }, { id: 'an2', displayValue: 'none' }, { id: 'wo2', displayValue: 'initial' }]
];

document.getElementById('myTable').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      const curElemetId = event.target.id;
      const btnIndex = (curElemetId === 'bt1') ? 1 : (curElemetId === 'bt2') ? 2 : -1;

      if ((btnIndex === 1) || (btnIndex === 2)) {
        const idx = btnIndex - 1;
        const { id, expectAns } = expectedElementAnswer[idx];

        if (getElementValue(id).toLowerCase() === expectAns) {
          changeDisplayStyles(idx);
        } else {
          setErrorWarning(curElemetId);
        }
      }
});

function changeDisplayStyles(idx) {
      btnElementList[idx].forEach(({ id, displayValue }) => {
        setDisplayStyle(id, displayValue)
      });
}

function setDisplayStyle(displayId, value) {
      document.getElementById(displayId).style.display = value;
}

function setErrorWarning(displayId, bgColor = 'red') {
      const element = document.getElementById(displayId);
      element.innerText = 'Wrong!';
      element.style.background = bgColor;
}

function getElementValue(id) {
      const value = document.getElementById(id)?.value || '';
      return value;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td class="c1">
        <input id="an1" placeholder="test" type="text"/>
        <a id="wo1" style="display: none;">test</a>
        <button id="bt1">Submit</button>
    </td>
    <td class="c1">test</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="c2">
        <input id="an2" placeholder="test1" type="text"/>
        <a id="wo2" style="display: none;">test1</a>
        <button id="bt2">Submit</button>
    </td>
    <td class="c2">test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```